# face recognition in c# using emgucv

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv

I'm trying to recognize a face in a photo using c# and emgucv, but I get stuck in a loop, on the last line here :

```
Image<Bgr, Byte> My_Image = new Image<Bgr, Byte>(dlg.FileName);
Image<Gray, Byte> gray = My_Image.Convert<Gray, Byte>(); 
HaarCascade face = new HaarCascade("haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml");
MCvAvgComp[][] facesDetected = gray.DetectHaarCascade(face);
```

also tried this :

```
MCvAvgComp[][] facesDetected1 = gray.DetectHaarCascade(
face, 1.1, 10,Emgu.CV.CvEnum.HAAR_DETECTION_TYPE.DO_CANNY_PRUNING, 
new Size(20, 20));
```

and it doesn't work either.

I'll appreciate any help :)

Comment: Didn't you mistake MCvAvgComp[][] for MCvAvgComp[,]?

Comment: nope, thats can't be build at both options.
i get a weird warning to these lines saying :

Warning 1 'Emgu.CV.Image<Emgu.CV.Structure.Gray,byte>.DetectHaarCascade(Emgu.CV.HaarCascade)' is obsolete: 'Use HaarCascade.Detect function instead. This function will be removed in the next release'

Comment: Hi, First does the example provided with EMGU. There should be no reason for the second part of code not to work unless gray is empty and no image is assigned. Use break points to asses the contents of gray. If not could you provide your source so I can have a look my article here will help as a reference in the mean time but is probably overkill for your need. http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/Face_Recognition.aspx. Also could you tell me what version of EMGU you are using so I can try and recreate your problem Cheers

Answer (score 4):

New code is like this

```
var HaarCascadeXML = new HaarCascade("haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml");
var faces = HaarCascadeXML.Detect(face, 1.1, 10, HAAR_DETECTION_TYPE.DO_CANNY_PRUNING,
                                  new Size(20, 20), new Size(BaseImage.Width, BaseImage.Height));
```

btw, It's merely a face detection not a face recognition